# Keep slide-toggled element at the top

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using jQuery `slideToggle()` to achieve an accordion effect. I'm not using the *actual* accordion control for specification and better customization reasons. The problem that I'm facing is that after the target element has been toggled, its parent does not maintain the vertical position, i.e. it slides down (see image bellow and [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jGnC6/)). I wasn't able to find anything useful in the Documentation and the other examples with "slide from bottom to top" do not correspond to my desired effect.

Is there any way to keep the parent at the same top vertical position?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your CSS:

```
.accordionWrapper {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/jGnC6/1/

This happens because you're using `display: inline-block;` to display the accordionWrappers; inline elements are vertically-aligned to the bottom by default.

[If you change your styles and use `float:left;` instead, you won't need the `vertical-align:top` property anymore.](http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/jGnC6/3/)

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I'm using `display: inline-block;` so that the layout maintains a "table like effect" and the collapsed elements do not "bundle" together like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jGnC6/4/), when you toggle, for example, the third and forth element (assuming  3 columns per row). The typical situation when solving an issue creates two other.